# Elements 11 inner glow

Tags: photoshop

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask this but I have an image that I am trying to add an inner glow to.  It all works fine if the glow is light coloured but as soon as I try to make the glow a darker colour then it just vanishes altogether.

Does anyone know why this is or how to add a black inner glow?

Comment: No, it's not really the right place. Did you read the tag description?: *'If you're not scripting for Photoshop, then your question belongs on Super User, Photography, or Graphic Design.'*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the functionality of Photoshop, a graphics program. It may be better suited for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blending modes play with the darkness and lightness as u can say ,

and there are 2 main sections that i usually use

1st) Darken modes (shows dark colors only)

> like **multiply** (it shows only black and dark colors and hides white

2nd) lighten modes (shows white colors only)

> like **screen** (which hides black and darken from the photo and appears white and lighten colors)

[check this page](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/layer-blend-modes/intro/) it may help you understanding blending modes

Answer (score 1):

Because the "Blend Mode" is set to Screen.

If you want to use Dark color, you can either:

Set the Blend mode to "Multiply"

OR

Use "Inner Shadow" instead of "Inner Glow".

The attached screenshot will clarify even more.

[image]